# Proper way to fork a project on GitHub to make major changes

Tags: github

I found an interesting project on GitHub ([a PHP Library](https://github.com/dineshrabara/2D-3D-Barcodes-Generator)) and I'm currently working on improving it.

I'm making big changes in the guy project. I'm changing the lib's architecture, fixing some bugs, adding some features, refactoring...

Since the changes are big, I don't plan to make a pull request for the guy to push my changes to his repo.

So here's my question:  Should I fork his repo, delete everything in it and push "my" code, or create a new repo and just make a link in the Readme informing people that this project is based on the guy's one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referring to the original meaning of a [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28software_development%29):

> a project fork happens when developers take a copy of source code from one software package and start independent development on it, creating a distinct piece of software

If your changes are so different from the original codebase, then your second option looks ok: new repo, and reference to the old one in the README.

A "[GitHub fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)" really makes sense when you want to collaborate back to the original repo.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations ! I'll create a new repo then.